# How have multiple init() with Swift

Tags: swift, init

Is it possible, if yes how, to have multiple init without parameter, in a Class like this (the string is just an exemple):

```
aVar: String

init() {
   aVar = "simple init"
}

initWithAGoodVar() {
   aVar = "Good Var!"
}

initWithFooBar() {
   aVar = "Foo Bar"
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at "convenience init" here : https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID215

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have multiple `init`s without parameters since it would be ambiguous which `init` method you wanted to use. As an alternative you could either pass the initial values to the `init` method. Taking the example from your question:

```
class MyClass {
    var myString: String

    init(myString: String) {
        self.myString = myString
    }
}

let a = MyClass(myString: "simple init")
```

Or, if `myString` is only supposed to be certain values, you could use an `enum`:

```
class MyOtherClass {
    enum MyEnum: String {
        case Simple  = "Simple"
        case GoodVar = "GoodVar"
        case FooBar  = "FooBar"
    }

    var myString: String

    init(arg: MyEnum) {
        myString = arg.rawValue
    }
}

let b = MyOtherClass(arg: .GoodVar)
println(b.myString) // "GoodVar"
```

Comment: We can have multiple `init` for a class with the use of `extension` for that class and define the particular `init` in that `extension`

Answer (score 4):

The `initWithSomething` is an Objective-C style, and it won't work exactly like that in Swift.

In Swift, all initializers are called `init` and can optionally take some parameters.

You could use default values like this:

```
class Example {
    var aVar: String

    init(goodVar : String = "Good Var!") {
        aVar = goodVar
    }
}

let example1 = Example()
println(example1.aVar) // prints "Good Var!"
```

However, this approach won't work exactly as in your example, because once you introduce the second `init` method, it's ambiguous which you wanted:

```
class Example {
    var aVar: String

    init(goodVar : String = "Good Var!") {
        aVar = goodVar
    }

    init(fooBar : String = "Foo Bar") {
        aVar = fooBar
    }
}

let example1 = Example() // error: cannot invoke initializer…
```

A better approach might be to use Swift's `enum`:

```
class Example {
    enum ExampleType : String {
        case GoodVar = "Good Var!"
        case FooBar = "Foo Bar"
    }

    var aVar: String

    init(type : ExampleType) {
        aVar = type.rawValue
    }
}

let example1 = Example(type: .GoodVar)
println(example1.aVar) // "Good Var!"

let example2 = Example(type: .FooBar)
println(example2.aVar) // "Foo Bar"
```

This approach will provide the flexibility you want using normal Swift syntax.

Comment: That's a seriously clever solution (enum).

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible to have multiple init, taking the same (or no) params.

But if you are looking for a way to construct objects with predefined states, you could use static factory methods:

```
class Test {

  let aVar: String

  init(aVar: String) {
    self.aVar = aVar
  }

  static func initWithAGoodVar() -> Test {
    return Test(aVar: "Good Var!")
  }

  static func initWithFooBar() -> Test {
    return Test(aVar: "Foo Bar")
  }
}

let test = Test.initWithFooBar()
println(test.aVar) // Prints: "Foo Bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have different init with different parameters.When you create a new instance of your class,the init method is called with the arguments you passed in

Comment: Mmm, that let me think to write init like this :
initWithParam(aGoodVar : Bool, fooBar : Bool) and launch the initializing according, but this seems not clean, no? Specially if I have 10+ parameters.

Comment: @grominet you can only use init for initialising the class.the is viewed like a function

Comment: maybe not possible with init, but passing argument will force me to create the object before each time I need it. And by a function, it let the risk to miss launching function.