# Why two-phase initialization isn't working for the class in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm started to learning swift and find a lesson named two-phase initialization. The example is given for structure and it's working properly for it. The example for structure type is given below:

```
import UIKit

struct NuclearRocket{
var meters: Double
var liters: Double

init(meters: Double, liters: Double){
    self.meters = meters
    self.liters = liters
    }
init(ft: Double, gallon: Double){
    let convertedMeters = ft / 3.28
    let convertedLiters = gallon * 3.78
    self.init(meters: convertedMeters , liters: convertedLiters)
        }
    }

var rocket = NuclearRocket(meters: 20, liters: 20)
rocket.liters
rocket.meters

var newRocket = NuclearRocket(ft: 2, gallon: 3)
newRocket.meters
newRocket.liters
```

It works properly and showing the exact output. But when I replace **struct** by **class** (Using **class NuclearRocket** instead of **struct NuclearRocket**) my compiler telling me that:

```
 Designated initializer for 'NuclearRocket' cannot delegate (with 'self.init'); did you mean this to be a convenience initializer?
```

What is the actual difference between using class and struct in this case?

Comment: Take a look at: https://medium.com/fantageek/convenience-init-in-swift-e0392e321f6

and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550640/how-have-multiple-init-with-swift

Comment: I understand what is convenient init is but can you tell me what is the exact difference of using a class instead of struct here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Swift class, a designated initializer can't call another designated initializer on itself. A designated initializer in a class can only call a designated initializer of its superclass (if there is one).

In a Swift class, a convenience initializer can only call a designated initializer on itself (not on a superclass if there is one).

These class rules come about due to class inheritance. The rules apply even if your class has no superclass. This is all covered in the Swift book under [Class Inheritance and Initialization](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216).

Your code as a class would work if you change the `init(ft: Double, gallon: Double)` initializer to a convenience initializer.

A Swift struct has slightly different rules since a struct doesn't support inheritance. A struct doesn't need to use convenience initializers which is why your original struct code worked. This is all covered in the Swift book under [nitializer Delegation for Value Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID215).

Comment: Thank's for your comment. Now it's very clear to me. Also thanks for the resource.