# How do I pass in a CustomCollectionView variable into this class?

Tags: swift

I have a class:

```
class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

// Cant pass it directly into the init because it is an override init :/
override init() {
    super.init()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

weak var delegate: layoutDelegate?
    
private var cache: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []

private var contentHeight: CGFloat = 0

private var contentWidth: CGFloat {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        print("Collectionview not found")
        return 0
    }
    let insets = collectionView.contentInset
    return collectionView.bounds.width - (insets.left + insets.right)
}

override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}

override func prepare() {
    guard
        cache.isEmpty,
        let collectionView = collectionView
    else { print("No Collectionview rip"); return }
    
    let columnWidth = contentWidth
    
    for item in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
        
        let postHeight = delegate?.collectionView(_collectionView: collectionView, heightForPostAtIndexPath: indexPath) ?? 200
        let height = postHeight
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: columnWidth, height: height)
        
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
        cache.append(attributes)
        
        contentHeight = max(contentHeight, frame.maxY)
    }
}

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var visibleLayoutAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = []
    
    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes in cache {
        if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
            visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return visibleLayoutAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    return cache[indexPath.item]
}
```

}

What I am trying to do is pass a variable called `CustomCollectionView` into this class so that I can use this variable instead of the default `collectionVIew`. However I am unsure how I am supposed to do this because this class has an `override init()` which doesn't allow you to pass variables into.

How do I pass a CustomCollectionView variable into this class?

Comment: You can create your own init method. Where the default init method initialize the collection view, and your new init e.g `init(with customCollectionView: UICollectionView)`. Or maybe create constructor function `static func createLayout(_ with collectionView: UICollectionView)`.

Comment: @E. Bogren Where do I put this `init(with customCollectionView: UICollectionVIew)`?

Comment: Next to the the one you currently have. You can have multiple init method.

Example from another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/30550886/3729825

Comment: @E. Bogren okay so I see what you are saying now and I have this: `init(customCollectionView: UICollectionView) {  collectionView = customCollectionView}`, but it is telling me collectionView is a get only property. What do you do in this case?

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, the layout already has a reference to the collection view. I'm not sure what the rest of your code look like but you could try to check if the collection view is of your custom class. E.g `guard let collectionView = collectionView, collectionView is CustomCollectionView`. Not sure that is a good approach, you can use the custom init and pass the values you need in your layout instead of accessing them off your collection view.

Comment: @E. Bogren I ended up just passing in my own collectionView through my custom init and I will use that instead of the default one which seems to work. Thanks for the help man I appreciate it!